# python beautifulsoup adding extra end tags

Tags: python, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I'm using Beautifulsoup to parse a website

```
  request = urllib2.Request(url)
  response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
  soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(response)
```

I am using it to traverse a table.  The problem I am running into is that BS is adding an extra end tag for the table into the html which doesn't exist, which I verified with: print soup.prettify().  So, one of the td tags is getting left out of the table and I can't select it.

Comment: Can you post the essential structure of the html code which is not working?

Comment: would love an answer to this as well. in my case, it seems BS is adding tags that are *not* in the page's source code

Answer (score 1):

How about searching directly for each  tag instead of trying to traverse into the table?

```
   for td in soup.find("td"):
        ...
```

its not unusual to find the tbody tag nested within a table automatically when its not in the code. Either you can code for it or just jump straight to the tr or td tag.

Comment: That's a good thought and I tried that.  When I run the code above it returns the whole table not each individual td.  I think BS is breaking on this pages horrible html ... bot sure what to do about it though

Comment: 2 things, check the version your using. If you're using 3.1 switch back to 3.0 (http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/3.1-problems.html) else try lxml, IMHO its a better general parser than Soup.